# python string parsing with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I can get numeric with this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '!"123%&654()')
['123', '654']
```

How can I get all the components ?

```
['!"', '123', '%&', '654', '()']
```

Comment: Did you try using `re.split`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No I didn't, `re.split(r'(\d+)', '!"123%&654()')` did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, with `findall`, you would greedily look for only digits, or only non-digits:

```
re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', '!"123%&654()')
# ['!"', '123', '%&', '654', '()']
```

`split` is a little cleaner.